# Why is my keyboard gets suddenly locked?

Tags: keyboard, freeze

I start normally my notebook lenovo 3000 N200 my version is 10.04. After many hours working on computer with mouse my keyboard gets locked.
 So I can't type anything, only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> is working. When I reboot I can use my keyboard. Sometimes is mouse locked too.
How can I lokalize this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the graphics server X freezing up rather than anything to do with the keyboard if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> still takes you to a terminal. It looks like that laptop has the Intel GM965 card in it so the problem is in that area.

Comment: Just as an aside: the GM965 has some of the best drivers of any chipset. I'm quite confident to say there will be nothing wrong with graphics drivers.